# Is chaining rows in the same table a bad pattern?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a tree structure of categories and need to find a proper way to store it into the database. Think of the following animal tree, which pretty accurately describes how it should look like:

[image: Animal Tree]

My question now is whether chaining those entries within the same table is a good idea or not. SQLite doesn't allow me to add a FOREIGN KEY constraint to a value in the same table, so I have to make sure manually that I don't create inconsistencies. This is what I currently plan to have:

```
id | parent | name
---+--------+--------
 1 | null   | Animal
 2 | 1      | Reptile
 3 | 2      | Lizard
 4 | 1      | Mammal
 5 | 4      | Equine
 6 | 4      | Bovine
```

`parent` references to an `id` in the same table, going up all the way until `null` is found, which is the root. Is this a bad pattern? And if so, what are common alternatives to put a tree structure into a relational database?

Comment: Your table is a recursive hierarchy, and is a fairly common thing in SQL.  The trick comes when you want to query the table to get certain questions answered.  Do you have a certain query/requirement in mind here?

Comment: Yeah, I want to search for a specific word using `LIKE` and then find all parent categories of the search result.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: The newest using SQLiteStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQLite supports recursive CTE, then this is one option:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS (
    SELECT id FROM yourTable WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.parent = t2.n AND t1.name NOT LIKE '%Lizard%'
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN cte;
```

This is untested, but the check on `t1.name` in the recursive portion of the above CTE (hopefully) should stop the recursion as soon we reach a record which matches the name in the `LIKE` expression.  In the case of searching for `Lizard`, the recursion should stop one level above Lizard, meaning that every record above it in the hierarchy should be returned.

Comment: `t2.n`, not `t2.id`.

Comment: Can't get it to work, unfortunately. It just returns an empty query. Thanks for the clue though, I'm gonna look further into this recursive function.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to change one of the table names. It worked like a charm. Thank you!